# Does the logistic function have a relation with $\arctan(x)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, exponential-function

The logistic function is: $$f(x)=\frac{L}{1+e^{-k(x-x_0)}}+B.$$

It's plot looks similar to the plot of $\arctan(x)$. Therefore, I was wondering whether there is a relationship between these two functions.

Can one transform the logistic function in such a way that it equals $\arctan(x)$? For example by giving the constants certain values?

Comment: no you can't simply  express one in term of the other :  with $L=k = 1$ and $B=x_0$ you get the [sigmoid function which fullfills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) $f'(x) = f(x)(1-f(x))$ while   $\text{arctan}'(x) = 1 + \text{arctan}(x)^2$. their graph on $\mathbb{R}$ and their differential equations are close

Answer (score 10):

One of the differences between a logistic function and the arctan is that the logistic function approaches its asymptotes exponentially, i.e. (if $k > 0$)
$$\eqalign{f(x) \sim L + B - L \exp(k x_0) \exp(-k x) & \ \text{as $x \to +\infty$}\cr
f(x) \sim B + L \exp(-k x_0) \exp(k x) & \ \text{as $x \to -\infty$}}$$
while the arctan approaches its asymptotes much more slowly, like $x^{-1}$:
$$ \eqalign{\arctan(x) \sim \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x} & \ \text{as $x \to +\infty$}\cr
    \arctan(x) \sim -\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x} & \ \text{as $x \to -\infty$}\cr}$$

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice comparison of sigmoid functions that you can find here: [Does the logistic function have a relation with arctan(x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669184/does-the-logistic-function-have-a-relation-with-arctanx)

specifically this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#/media/File:Gjl-t(x).svg

You probably want to compare your sigmoid function on equal footing to arctangent, in both domain and range so you'd want something like $1+\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(kx)$

They do not share any real relationship other than both being "sigmoidal functions", and become more similar as $k$ goes to 0 or infinity.

Comment: Your first link is to this same page.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Hm, what if that was a page and its link is broken because of this question?  Just wondering if thats possible.

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a look at the inverse functions of the logistic function and arctan

Consider the sigmoid
$$sigmoid(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$$
It's inverse function is
$$logit(x)=\log(\frac{x}{1-x})$$

Now the comparison becomes much clearer.

$tan$ is periodic ($tan(x)=tan(x+2k\pi)$), while $logit$ is not.

The $logit$ is a bijection, while $tan$ is not

Comment: this seems to miss the heart of the question. Logit is only defined on $[0,1]$ and can perfectly well be compared with $\tan(x)$ on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, both of which are "bijections" on their respective intervals. You could just as well extend logit periodically if you wanted to retain periodicity.